# Move widget area on inner pages

Tags: widget, genesis

I have added a widget area to my home page below front page 1 all good, what i want to do is on all pages except the home page have the same widget but just move it to above the footer

the above just shows the widget above the footer on all pages - can some one point me in the right direction please thanks in advance`enter code here`

```
        genesis_register_sidebar( array(
        'id' => 'newsletter',
        'name' => __( 'Newsletter Widget', 'genesis' ),
        'description' => __( 'Newsletter Widget Area', 'monochrome-pro' ),
        ) );

        add_action( 'genesis_after_front-page-1_widget_area', 'add_genesis_widget_area' );
        if ( is_home() && is_front_page() ) {
        function add_genesis_widget_area() {
              genesis_widget_area( 'newsletter', array(
                'before' => '<div class="newsletter widget-area">',
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
        }
        }

        add_action( 'genesis_after_footer', 'add_genesis_widget_area2' );
        if ( !is_home() && !is_front_page() ) {
        function add_genesis_widget_area2() {
              genesis_widget_area( 'newsletter', array(
                'before' => '<div class="newsletter widget-area">',
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
        }
        }
```